# Доступ к ноутбуку (Ubuntu16.04) из телефона (Android 6) в одной сети wifi

Tags: android, ubuntu, wifi

Дома стоит роутер к которому подключен по wifi телефон(андроид) и ноутбук(убунту 16.04). Читал, что если оба устройства подключены к одному роутеру, то локальная сеть уже есть. Для того, чтобы иметь доступ к ноутбуку достаточно в телефоне в браузере ввести внутренний ip компьютера, ну и нужно ,чтобы он был активен конечно. Однако, введя внутренний ip ноутбука в браузере телефона ничего не происходит. Пишет, что нет связи с сайтом. Проверял коммандой ping с обеих устройств - пакеты отправляются и возвращаются.

Для чего мне это нужно. На ноутбуке стоит lamp. На нем я запускаю php сайты (для разработки) . Хотелось бы получить доступ к сайту не только на этом пк, но и на телефоне для визуального тестирования верстки.

Comment: у вас запущен веб-сервер на ноутбуке и вы хотите зайти на него с телефона, находящегося в той локальной сети? Что происходит, если адрес, который вы в телефоне вводите (к примеру, `http://172.17.0.1:8888/`) ввести на ноутбуке?

Comment: А что это за адрес?

Comment: *"который вы в телефоне вводите"*

Comment: Ага. Понял. В браузере пк пишу его же адрес ip в локальной сети и 
  и порт .Пишет Access forbidden!

Comment: В адрес вбиваю 192.168.2.103:80 You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected. Нужно куда-то добавить индексный файл, только куда?

Comment: как настроить веб-сервер, чтобы он желаемую страницу показывал — это отдельный вопрос, никакого отношения к к телефону не имеет. Если самостоятельно не получится, задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: А чем этот вопрос не ясен? Так можно и про убунту сказать. Я просто описал проблему.

Comment: на stack overflow принято разные вопросы как разные вопросы задавать. Это не обычный форум, где вы начали с одной проблемы, нашли другую, потом третью итд и продолжаете обсуждать всё в кучу в одной ветке. Задав отдельно вопрос "как в X веб-сервере свою index страницу показать" вы можете помочь людям с похожей проблемой (их число может больше числа людей, которых одновременно интересует как по локальной сети с телефона веб-страничку запросить — отдельный вопрос про настройки сети, в качестве сервера для отладки можно хоть `python3 -m http.server` использовать).

Comment: Меня интересует именно этот вопрос, с этими вводными. Помогите или не мешайте.

Comment: Тяжелый случай.

Answer (score 0):

В общем доступ к пк на убунту блокировал фаервол. Он идет из коробки в 16.04 .Если отключить его и зайти на локальный ip пк с телефона , то сайт на lampp виден в браузере. 
Вот как отключить фаервол sudo ufw disable,а включить sudo ufw enable .